# Hibernate Criteria for entity with embedded objects

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity "UserDetails" which has the following variables:

1. String userId
2. String userName
3. UserContact userContact (where UserContact is an Embeddable class)

UserContact has the following variables:

1. String phoneNumber
2. String email
3. String city

What will be a Hibernate Criteria for fetching the following list:

Users with userName = 'sam' and with city = 'New York'

I tried the following and got the runtime exception that it doesn't recognize the variable 'city':

```
List<UserLogin> list = session.createCriteria(UserLogin.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("userName","sam"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("city", "New York"))
    .list();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh I figured it out...

```
List<UserLogin> list = session.createCriteria(UserLogin.class)
   .add(Restrictions.eq("userName","sam"))
   .add(Restrictions.eq("userContact.city", "New York"))
   .list();
```

Silly, just needed to add 'userContact.city' instead of 'city', where userContact is the object of the class UserContact in my entity.